# Reset Galaxy tab without losing apps in SD Card

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have an old `Samsung Galaxy Tab`, it keeps on lagging and has delays. I want to reset it, if I do will the newly reset Tab still acknowledge the apps stored in the SD Card? Thank you.

Comment: I just flashed a new ROM to my Galaxy Tab 1 last week and the data on the external SD card was intact. Please clarify what you mean by "apps" stored in the SD card? Do you mean apps that are "moved" to SD card, or do you mean app data or app backups?

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

No.

### Explanation

One purpose of a reset, and why it's called [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset), is to set it back to the state it came from the factory. This means, all user apps and user data is "removed" (de facto, `/data` and `/cache` are wiped). Usually, only internal storage is affected this way, and SD cards are left untouched unless explicitly specified (I write "usually" as some manufacturers/ROMs deviate from this).

That said: your "apps on SD card" will be gone even without the SD card being touched, as:

1. [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd) doesn't move the entire app to SD card (but only parts)
2. Android would forget about those apps anyway, as information on packages installed resides in `/data/system/packages.xml` – and you remember, `/data` gets wiped by the factory-reset.

Comment: +1, I believe `/data/system/packages.xml`should've been a teaser for Short Answer.

Comment: @Firelord that would make the "short answer" 5 (or more) times longer :)